# Updating Pivot Table in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, pivot-table, eloquent

I am using laravel-5.3. I am having some issues to updating the tables. Suppose i have two modles(Research and Member). Both have many-to-many relations. I have a pivot table named member_research. This table has the following columns:

- research_id
- member_id
- role

So when i am trying to update some research i might have to update the research members and their roles too along with other info. I am actually trying the following way:

```
$Research = Researches::find($request->id);
$Research->Member->all();

foreach ($Research->member as $id){
    $id->pivot->role = $role;
    $id->pivot->save();
}
```

in this approach the role is updating finely. but when i am trying to update the member_id it is not working. Here is the code

```
$Research = Researches::find($request->id);
$Research->Member->all();

foreach ($Research->member as $id){
    $id->pivot->member_id = $new_id ;
    $id->pivot->save();
}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What are the names of your models and relations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should not update the IDs in the pivot table manually.**

Related records that get unlinked should be removed from pivot table and new relations should be defined by inserting new rows into the pivot table.

If you want to update role for selected member you can use **updateExistingPivot()** method:

```
$research->members()->updateExistingPivot($memberId, ['role' => $newRole]);
```

If you want to link a member to a research and set the role, use the **save()** method:

```
$research->members()->attach($memberId, ['role' => $newRole]);
```

If you want to unlink a member from a research, use **detach()** method:

```
$research->members()->detach($memberId);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried updateExistingPivot() and sync() methode too. But still is not updating :(

Comment: Could you update the question with your models and current controller code?